# Better way to write a join query in ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

I have two tables CustomerBalance and Customer which are bound with CustomerRefId field.
I want the CustomerBalance records that are lets say greater than 100 for a field balance of this tables. I also want to include into my results the name of the particular customer that fulfills that criteria. I created the following method that works!

```
public List<CustomerBalance> getCustomerBalanceFilter(String filterVal) {
    try {
        PreparedQuery<CustomerBalance> preparedQuery = mDbHelper.getCustomerBalanceDao().queryBuilder()
            .where().gt(CustomerBalance.DB_COL_CUSTOMER_BALANCE, filterVal)
            .prepare();
        List<CustomerBalance> result = mDbHelper.getCustomerBalanceDao().query(preparedQuery); 

        for(CustomerBalance alert : result) {
            PreparedQuery<Customer> getCustQuery = mDbHelper.getCustomerDao().queryBuilder()
                .where().eq(Customer.DB_COL_CUSTOMER_REF_ID, alert.getCustomerID())
                .prepare();
            List<Customer> customer = mDbHelper.getCustomerDao().query(getCustQuery);

            alert.setCustomer(customer.size() == 1 ? customer.get(0) : null);
        }

        return result;

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This methods is working, is this the best way to write such a query? or is there a more appropriate approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One improvement to your query is to use [ORMLite's](http://ormlite.com/) `SelectArg` to pass in the customer-id instead of a new query each time.  Something like:

```
...
List<CustomerBalance> result = mDbHelper.getCustomerBalanceDao()
    .query(preparedQuery); 

SelectArg custIdArg = new SelectArg();
PreparedQuery<Customer> getCustQuery = mDbHelper.getCustomerDao().queryBuilder()
    .where().eq(Customer.DB_COL_CUSTOMER_REF_ID, custIdArg)
    .prepare();
for (CustomerBalance alert : result) {
    custIdArg.setValue(alert.getCustomerID());
    List<Customer> customer = mDbHelper.getCustomerDao().query(getCustQuery);
    alert.setCustomer(customer.size() == 1 ? customer.get(0) : null);
}
```

Here are the docs for `SelectArg`:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/select-arg

FYI, there also is an `UpdateBuilder`, but I don't see an easy way to turn your code above into a single `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much Gray! I use this method just for fetching data, so there is no need for the time being for Update operation.

Comment: So, nested query is the recommended way to solve the problem that ORMLite can't get "joined" object?